# как сделать так, чтобы фиксированный элемент не выходил за пределы родительского блока?

Tags: javascript, css

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="left">Меню слева</div>
  <div class="center">Контент</div>
  <div class="right">Меню справа</div>
</div>
```

У левого и правого меню задано фиксированное позиционирование, у блока с контентом по умолчанию. Высота родительского блока равна высоте блока с контентом. Как сделать, так чтобы фиксированный элементы не выходили за пределы родительского блока?
[пример](https://brandshop.ru/goods/358274/gy4419/)

Comment: Что именно вы пробовали уже?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `position: sticky`

Comment: Спасибо больше, sticky работает